# Do I need $|u|=1$ to prove $D_uf(a)=\langle \nabla f(a),u\rangle$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation

I'm reading this [book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=34Ic0K3LQxEC&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and I would like to know where the authors are using the fact of $|u|=1$ in the proof.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is used in the first equation, which stands alone, namely
$$\frac{f(a+tu)-f(a)}{t}-\left<\nabla f(a),u\right>=\frac{|t|}{t}\epsilon(a+tu)\|u\|=\frac{|t|}{t}\epsilon(a+tu),$$
but you don't need to do this there.

Answer (score 1):

Notice $\|tu\|=|t|$ if and only if $\|u\|=1$ (for $t\neq 0$, but we are taking limit as $t\to 0$ so it doesn't matter).

When you go from $f(a+tu)=f(a)+\langle\nabla f(a),u \rangle +\epsilon(a+tu)\|tu\|$ to next line, you need precisely the fact that $\|tu\|=|t|$